# How to remove Request_install_package permission from flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, google-play-console

I want to publish my android app written in flutter. Play Console have rejected my request. The problem is request_install_package permission. So i want to delete it but in release report i saw that many of my packages uses this permission. How to solve this problem?

I try to delete all my packages which use this permission, but actualy i cant run my application without this packages. I also try to remove permission from androidmanifest but it doesnt work.

Comment: can you post your pubspec here? Also, Can you explain which packages you use that need this permission? What feature breaks after you remove packages?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.